# Is there something that starts timer to make an action?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is there something, that puts a timer for making an action after days, in php.

Like if I have blocked users table in DB... I've put it to the table, and let's say I want to remove it from blocked user table after 5 days... is there something that automates it???

Hope I asked correctly and you understood my thought

Comment: You could use SQL EVENTS, you could use a cron job, there's a couple of options for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the time when the user was banned, and the ban duration in the database.

When the user attempts to access his account, make a check whether it is before (still banned) or after (unbanned) `banDate + banDuration`.

Another approach would be to use **[crontab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)** or a similar service to periodically check for ban times.

Comment: but each time it's unnecessary checking and unnecessary query making

Comment: @user2779986: How many banned people are you expecting to get? Such a trivial query once in a while isn't going to be significant. Nevertheless, if you want it to be accurate, that's how you do it.

Comment: @user2779986: Make note that crontab is only as accurate as the period you're checking it. So if you can give a 5 hour ban, don't make daily checks, make a check every 10 minutes or so, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When user will login check duration. If last login time minus now time < 5 days then user is blocked, else log in him

Answer (score 0):

I see two solutions:

1. Make cron task, every example 4 hours and write script to check all ban times
2. Check ban time after login, you can use sessions or cookies to limit SQL queries - try to storage ban time in cookie, when cookie exist - don't make query

Comment: but then I can easily delete my cookies.

Comment: yes but when cookie don't exist, script must make query; also, when value in cookie suggest that ban time is over, script also must make query. It's safe and may save db from many queries.

Comment: What about the situation where another user would want to login from the same machine? The ban is no longer user specific but machine specific.

Comment: Let me explain... 1. Check if cookie "ban=user:bantime" 2. If not, do query 3. If yes, check bantime; if bantime is over, make query 4. If login =/= user, make query (and maybe set another cookie)